# Invalid provisional profile error after using `ipa build` and `deliver` tool (automating app submission)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, fastlane

I've been using the `fastlane` tool provided at: https://fastlane.tools to generate provisional profiles and submit apps to iTunes connect.

Sequence of commands:

```
$fastlane init
$cert
$produce
$sigh
```

Following this the provisional profile corresponding to distribution on App store is automatically downloaded. After which the `deliver` command is executed and as per the [guide](https://github.com/KrauseFx/deliver) this statement was added in the deliverfile -

```
ipa do
      system("ipa build --verbose") 
      "./AppName.ipa" 
end
```

It successfully generates the `.ipa` file but fails to submit the app to iTunes connect. The following error is generated -

> [15:57:54]: [Transporter Error Output]: ERROR ITMS-90161: "Invalid Provisioning Profile. The provisioning profile included in the bundle com.razeware.ScaryBugsZo [Payload/ScaryBugsZo.app] is invalid. [Missing code-signing certificate]. A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when submitting apps to the App Store. For more information, visit the iOS Developer Portal."

Although on using the same provisional profile generate by `fastlane` I'm able to upload the build using xCode. My final goal is to automate submission of multiple apps on iTunes connect from a single apple ID. For this, `sigh` is successfully generating provisional profiles. I need to a way to automate uploading the build either by using `deliver` or some other method.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend checking out the official [fastlane code signing guide](https://github.com/KrauseFx/fastlane/blob/master/docs/CodeSigning.md) that shows you the various ways to do code signing.